# Replace characters in field on form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery

For example, if the field value was "John Wayne" I would want it to be replaced with "John_Wayne"

I'm thinking I can accomplish this through jQuery, basic idea is below:

```
$('#searchform').submit(function() {

//take current field value
//replace characters in field
//replace field with new value

});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use the overload of [`val`](http://api.jquery.com/val) that takes a function:

```
$("input:text").val(function (i, value) {
    /* Return the new value here. "value" is the old value of the input: */
    return value.replace(/\s+/g, "_");
});
```

(You'll probably want your selector to be more specific than `input:text`)

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/nTXse/

Comment: +1: I didn't know that overload existed. This is good for jQuery 1.4+.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using the `g` global on the replace?
`.replace(/\s+/g, "_", "g");`

Comment: @Indranil: You're absolutely right, I'd forgotten the `flags` parameter was non-standard. Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to look at all of your form elements without specifying them individually, you could do something like:

```
$('#searchform').submit(function() {
    $.each($(':input', this), function() {
        $(this).val($(this).val().replace(' ', '_'));
    });
});
```

You might have to pay attention to the type of the element, and that it's visible, enabled, a certain type, etc.

---

**EDIT:** I would use Andrew's answer. This was just the first solution that popped into my head. This one might ultimately give you slightly more control over each field in your form, but Andrew's is short and sweet.

Answer (score 0):

Use the onkeyup HTML element attribute and regular expressions:

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[Search Expression]/flag,'New String');">
```

This solution prevents the user from typing a value outside the pattern established by the regex.

For your case, use:

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[\s]/g, '_');">
```

Comment: Thanks for your first collaboration. However you could use markdown fences to show code instead of using bold.  https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting

Comment: Maybe the best event to attach this regex would be "onChange", because it prevents the user from bypassing "onKeyUp" (likewise "OnKeyDown", both keyboard raised events) with context menu ("right click").